# Module build failed: ReferenceError: [BABEL] /app/src/index.js: Unknown option: /app/node_modules/react/react.js.Children

Tags: node.js, babeljs

My project fails with the error message in title on heroku, but it works locally.

This is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0']
      }
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.jsx', '.js']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  }
};
```

And this is `package.json`:

```
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive ./test",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.24.1",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-jquery": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.1",
    "jsdom": "^8.1.0",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3",
    "react-redux": "4.3.0",
    "react-router": "^2.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.0.0",
    "redux": "^3.0.4",
    "redux-form": "^6.6.3",
    "redux-promise": "^0.5.3",
    "validator": "^9.1.2",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.4"
  }
}
```

I digged around a bit, trying to find an answer, but there was no case such as working on one machine, and not on another machine.

**Update 1**

Here is `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import promise from 'redux-promise';

import reducers from './reducers';

import LoginForm from './components/login_form';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(promise)(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Route path="/" component={LoginForm} />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

** Update 2 **
I tried changing the `jsx` to `js` for the `test` property in webpack `loader` config object, it didn't help. I removed `stage-1` and it's still failing.

Comment: Can we see `index.js`?

Comment: @Li357 I updated the question and added `index.js` content.

Comment: Did you deliberately leave out `test:/\.jsx?$/` in `loaders`?

Comment: I added `test:/\.js?$/` to the `module.loader` and I still get the same error. 
I tried `jsx`, and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: I cannot see the error, but I would comment that you're using the latest of some things, like babel; but really old versions of things like React... Maybe something just got broken because of a round of deprecation?

Comment: any suggestion on how to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem got fixed:

1. Deleted `module.query` and `resolve` from the webpack config file.
2. Moved dependencies from `devDependencies` to `dependencies` (heroku is a production environment, and therefore it doesn't download `devDependencies`, which doesn't make sense to me !)